# why does swift dictionary with function work outside of a class but produces error inside of a class?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

I came across this issue (and thanks to playground I was able to locate it)

I try to use a dictionary, that has numbers as keys and functions as values. Everything works fine outside of a class:

```
private func hello1(x: Double) {
    println("hello1")
}
private func hello2(x: Double) {
    println("hello2")
}

private let contacts: [Int: Double -> ()] = [
    0 : hello1,
    1 : hello2
]

contacts[1]?(1.0) // Works fine :-)
```

When I put the identical code inside a class, I get a compiler error

> 'Double' is not a subtype of 'SomeClass'

With the identical code:

```
internal class SomeClass {
    private func hello1(x: Double) {
        println("hello1")
    }
    private func hello2(x: Double) {
        println("hello2")
    }

    private let contacts: [Int: Double -> ()] = [ // *** Here I get the error ***
        0 : hello1,
        1 : hello2
    ]

    internal func runIt() {
        contacts[1]?(1.0)
    }
}

let someClass = SomeClass()
someClass.runIt()
```

I tried several ways of brackets. No improvements.

What did I missed when learning Swift? What did I misunderstand or misinterpret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hello1` and `hello2` is a instance method. If they were referenced as `SomeClass.hello1`, the type would be `SomeClass -> (Double) -> ()`. So you can call it like this:

```
var foo = SomeClass()
SomeClass.hello1(foo)(1.0)
```

It's like a curried function. and this is why you got the error `'Double' is not a subtype of 'SomeClass'`.

If you want to do what you want, you should do like this:

```
internal class SomeClass {
    private func hello1(x: Double) {
        println("hello1")
    }
    private func hello2(x: Double) {
        println("hello2")
    }

    lazy private var contacts: [Int: Double -> ()] = [
        0 : self.hello1,
        1 : self.hello2
    ]

    internal func runIt() {
        contacts[1]?(1.0)
    }
}
```

You have to use `lazy var` instead of `let`, or you cannot reference `self`.

---

ADDED:

Above code makes strong reference cycles. you should use closures with `[unowned self]`.

```
lazy private var contacts: [Int: Double -> ()] = [
    0 : {[unowned self] in self.hello1($0) },
    1 : {[unowned self] in self.hello2($0) }
]
```

Comment: Man, you made my day! I use this piece of code in a SpriteKit Game to keep the `didBeganContact()` as generic as possible.